# function two command how can use

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

How to make Main() linked to commandajax()

Make commandajax() where you can use the two instructions

"savecmd" and "catcmd" it?

```
//The initial loading screen
function Main()
{

  //Read floag
  alert("Main:");
  var savecmd = "echo -n \"save"+"\" > /app/Web/cgi-bin/login.txt";
  var catcmd = "cat /app/Web/cgi-bin/login.txt";

  var floag = funtion(command, isMsg);
```

command function:

```
function commandajax(command, isMsg)
{
    var ReturnString = "";
    var ipAddress = location.protocol+"//"+location.hostname+"/cgi-bin/";
    var URLs = ipAddress + "PProduceXml.php";
    alert(2);
    //  var savecmd = "echo -n \"save"+"\" > /app/Web/cgi-bin/login.txt";
    //  var catcmd = "cat /app/Web/cgi-bin/login.txt";
    //  alert("Action=TransmissionStart&submitString="+(savecmd,catcmd));

    $.ajax(
        {
        ----
        {
            alert("msg:"+msg);
            if(isMsg == true)
            {
                ReturnString = msg;
            }
        },
        error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
        {
        }
    });

    return ReturnString;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "linked"?

Comment: Main() can call back commandajax() function